# Combining tangentially related study results to form a single probability in forensic pathology

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am a forensic pathologist with a question about combining perpetrator studies into one probability.  For instance, let's say I know the following regarding male vs female assailants in murder cases:

Attack at night:

Male assailant:  70% night, 30% day
Female assailant: 40% night, 60% day

Multiple injuries on victim:

Male: 80% > 10 injuries, 20% < 10 injuries
Female: 30% > 10 injuries, 70% < 10 injuries

Known to victim:

Male: 40% known, 60% stranger
Female: 80% known, 20% stranger

Note that none of these percentages are real; I'm just using this as a toy example.

So, I have a victim that suffered 15 injuries, attacked at night, by a stranger (assume I actually know all these things).  What is the probability the assailant was male?

What test should I use?  I assume I need to know prevalence data (e.g. how many assailants in general are male vs female).

Is this a Bayesian thing?  Do I need to chain them?  If so, how can I calculate the priors?

For one study, for instance, I understand that

$P(\text{male} | \text{night})= P(\text{night} | \text{male} ) \cdot P(\text{male})/P(\text{night})$

And there are studies that will give me P(male), P(night), and even P(night|male).

But now, what about adding the next one:

$P(\text{male} | \text{night}, \text{stranger}) = P(\text{night}, \text{stranger} | \text{male}) \cdot P(\text{male})/P(\text{night}, \text{stranger})$

and on and on.

I don't think there's a study for the $P(\text{night}, \text{stranger}, \text{multiple wounds})$ equivalent prior for my particular problem.

Is there a way to do this without knowing that prior well?

Comment: You can't get there from here, because your information about *marginal* probabilities does not fully encode the *joint* probabilities.  For instance, you can't determine the rate of assailants at night by males known to the victim.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  If all of the studies point to male, I suppose I can just go with the one with the highest marginal probability.  But that is even more confusing to me.  For instance, if my victim was attacked at night by a stranger, but has only one wound, then I have two features favoring male and one favoring female.  It seems that I have to fall back to Baconian-type inference where I count evidence categorically and just sum them.  That's the traditional way, but it's unsatisfying when you actually have a little real data to work with.

Comment: Thanks to Igor F. for the formatting.  Clearly this is not an area of my primary expertise...